# How can I demonstrate to contractors that a gas pipeline is unused?

Tags: gas, pipeline

We are trying to build a home on an empty lot. There is an abandoned 6" gas pipeline running through where we are able to build it. We've done a lot of work to understand the history of this pipeline already. It was originally a gas pipeline but was sold to a telecom company a few decades ago. It eventually changed hands to Verizon after several companies had been bought. We worked with Verizon and they agreed to terminate the right of way around the pipe, because they are not using it, and saw no future economic use for it. We thought we were good to go, but no contractor will touch this pipe with a ten foot pole. They say the same thing, get someone else to make the initial cut, then I'll remove it.

Verizon cut into the line 1-2 miles away from our lot to redirect the telecom wires to another conduit that already existed. That is why they no longer needed it. So we know that this thing is not pressurized with gas. But I need a way to prove it to the contractors. Is there any sort of service that can test for gas in pipes and prove they are decommissioned/abandoned?

Comment: First make sure you have everything in writing about the line/easement/right of way and have it removed from the land.  For the pipe itself, maybe a local gas company can help, but I don't blame the others for not wanting to touch it.  Gas plus spark makes for a bad day, even just cutting empty barrels can be bad.

Comment: How convinced are you that the line is truly empty of gas? If a few holes "magically" appeared in the pipe one day would the contractor be OK with pulling the rest? How much excitement are you prepared to deal with if the pipe is not empty of gas?

Comment: Are you willing to risk your life/limbs to test show the contractor that the pipe is not used?

Comment: @JonCuster  Flumes can last for a long time.  Old empty fuel containers need special handling before cutting into.  Was a story years ago about a student cutting an empty peppermint oil barrel.  It was did not end well.  This is a job for a gas pro with license and insurance.

Comment: @crip659 - yup. indeed. Old silane (pyrophoric) high purity stainless piping would retain enough silane on the interior surfaces to make some pretty good jets of flame out the ends if, e.g., bent or dropped. Disilane only made it more exciting.

Comment: Is this pipe plastic or steel?

Comment: Maybe a friendly person at Verizon can tell you what firm they use.

Comment: You might want to start with a lawyer. What did your deed say?

Comment: We worked with a lawyer to remove the right of way. It is definitely gone, paperwork file and approved with the county.

Comment: I'm not willing to cut the pipe myself. I understand their hesitancy. That is why I'm looking for an expert to help with it. The pipe has been owned and used by telecom for more than 20 years, I don't see how any gas could be left in it.

Comment: We found a plumber who is willing to do it. I showed him our documentation and he's looking over it. So hopefully he will. He said he's cut gas line plenty of times before.